# How to assign space/null value to a 2D array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, 2d

Im trying to print a Int 2D array with a null value. Which is basically like assigning a space in String array.

```
int[,] arr = new int[10, 10];
for (int temp = 0; temp < arr.GetLength(0); temp++)
{
 for (int temp2 = 0; temp2 < arr.GetLength(1); temp2++)
  {
    arr[temp, temp2] = xxxxx ;
   }
}

for (int xIndex = 0; xIndex < arr.GetLength(0); xIndex++)
{
  for (int yLoop = 0; yLoop < arr.GetLength(1); yLoop++)
   {
    Console.Write(arr[xIndex, yLoop]);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

So far I tried assigning null value but I got "Cannot convert null to 'int' because it is a non-nullable value type.
If I dont assign any value it just simply output 0 's and I want it to be display nothing in console.

Answer (score 2):

Defining int as nullable type will resolve your issue, just declare the array as :

`int?[,] arr = new int?[10, 10];`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot assign a NaN-Value to an int. Every possible value of an int is a number, if you want that nothing is displayed instead of 0 you have to work around this somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if your 2D array contains null values, just check if that value is null and if it is, print nothing. The issue here is that your array is declared as an `int` array, so it can't contain null.
A possible workaround would be to assign negative values instead of "null" if your actual array values are all positive. That way, you can check for that value.

```
int[,] arr = new int[10, 10];
for (int temp = 0; temp < arr.GetLength(0); temp++) {
  for (int temp2 = 0; temp2 < arr.GetLength(1); temp2++) {
    arr[temp, temp2] = xxxxx; // set to -1 if the value is unknown / undefined etc.
  }
}

for (int xIndex = 0; xIndex < arr.GetLength(0); xIndex++) {
  for (int yLoop = 0; yLoop < arr.GetLength(1); yLoop++) {
    if (arr[xIndex, yLoop] >= 0) {
      Console.Write(arr[xIndex, yLoop]);
    }
    else {
      Console.Write(" ");
    }
  }
  Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try making `int` a nullable type so you could assign null to it. This should be true or all other value types too like `double` or `bool`. Just change `int[,]` to `int?[,]`.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to print to console simply use if condition to print a space..

int[,] arr = new int[10, 10];
// you dont need to assign values. By default its 0

```
for (int xIndex = 0; xIndex < arr.GetLength(0); xIndex++)
{
  for (int yLoop = 0; yLoop < arr.GetLength(1); yLoop++)
   {
    if(arr[xIndex, yLoop]==0)
    {
       Console.Write(" ");
    }
   }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```